# How to stop an application for a self-update?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

My app needs to be able to update itself. In order to do so, when I click on the app's update to start the installation, it should stop and restart after installation is complete. Can Windows do that for me somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your application into 2 parts: `main application` and `updater`. You can call the updater from the main app (**and stop the main app**), do all the update stuff, then **relaunch** the main app from the updater.

Comment: You cannot change the executable file while it is running (except in really old versions of Windows). This is by design as a security features. You can put all of the logic in your main application to download a new version or patches to the main executable, but you have to perform the actual changes from a different. I have seen people use a .CMD script as the seperate executable, which does nothing more than some renames and then relaunch the original executable -- so I can be be simple.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment(v=vs.90).aspx -- Just remembered this. Brain a little slow this morning.

Comment: @Sergey I've thought of this, but I was hoping Windows had some mechanism already implemented for this. How can I check whether the installer finished its execution or not, in order to relaunch the main app? Thank you :) I think this solves my problem.

Comment: @theDane: the installer should relaunch the main app. It knows when it finished its work.